# Import .CSV file to replace a specific empty field (not null) in SQL?

Tags: sql, csv

I have been looking but I don't think I have been asking the correct question. I have a database of employees that I imported via SQL with a .CVS file. The issue I have now is, when you normally add an employee via the website, a unique link is created for each person but because I imported, the site never created a unique link for each one. I am able to copy and past for each one and just change the last(two,three) digit but its a bit over 300 employees. Is there a better way? Could I import another .CVS file just for the field?

Comment: What kind of "link" are you talking about?

Comment: Its a link that takes them to an electronic handbook so they can review and sign it. The Link that is generated in SQL shows up as *****-****-****-****-************.

Comment: But with numbers and letters.

Comment: Seems like you need to figure out how to create this "link" for all the employees that are missing it.   But then, it's hard to say without knowing more about your application and database.

Comment: And what DBMS are you using? SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc. Please tag it as each have their own csv facilities.

Comment: As far as I know, most csv import methods do not support `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY` features; though I am admittedly not very familiar with such methods. If the csv is well formed, you could perhaps use a regex replace function (in a text editor such as Notepad++) to convert the lines into `UPDATE` queries.